# Can a U.S. county secede from a U.S. state?

Tags: united-states, borders, federalism

Assume a county in State A wanted to join State B. Would that be possible? If so, what would be the procedure? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, it has been done.  West Virginia.

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't think that's accurate. West Virginia became its own independent state. It did not join an existing state. This question is about the latter scenario. Not the former.

Comment: @RainWillow, does this question inspired by that story with Oregon-Idaho https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2020/02/17/oregon-idaho-border-petition-secede/4789936002/ ? It seems, that it is juridically possible. But I doubt if burocracy would allow this.

Comment: @user2501323: Actually, I heard about this in reference to a different scenario. It was two states in the mid-Atlantic region, I believe. But, apparently, it can happen anywhere.

Comment: Regarding tags, I'm not sure what "federalism" and even more so "states rights" ("questions related to the balance of power between the US Federal government and State governments") have to do with this poorly fleshed out question,,,, Please used the edit function to clarify the question rather than a series of comments. In particular, you didn't make clear in the question if "State B" is an existing US state or not...

Comment: @RainWillow:  West Virginia was created by the counties that suceeded from Virginia proper after Virginia succeeded from the Union at the beginning of the civil war.   At the time, the U.S. government basically treated WV as if it was the legitament government of VA... which is why I like to joke that we should rename WV to Virgina and VA to "Stupid Virginia."   In a similar situation, the area around Arlington VA was formerly part of D.C. (not a state) that was returned to Stupid Virginia in the 20th century+

Comment: +Additionally, Kentucky was formally part of Virginia and the Maine was in some parts once Massachusetts.

Comment: @Fizz: I think it's pretty clear that B is already a state because of the contextual clues which include the words "join" and "state." You can't "join" a state that's not a state. And you can't be a "state" unless you are a state. So I'm not sure how much clearer that point can be. Is there some other aspect of the question that can be clarified? Regarding the tags, "federalism" applies because the political and legal question at play span multiple levels of government: federal, state and local. And "states rights" could apply if the supremacy clause were invoked to block secession.

Comment: Is this a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It's not a whole county, but Ellis Island (home of the Statue of Liberty) has been claimed by both New York and New Jersey, and has caused some border disputes between the two states.  There's probably other examples of borders shifting around (e.g. due to river courses changing over time), but not as large as a whole county.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Ellis Island is not the home of the Statue of Liberty.  That is the former Bledsoe's Island, now called Liberty Island.  Ellis Island is currently shared by New York and New Jersey; parts of the island that were created by landfill after the change in the riverine border from the west bank to the center line belong to New Jersey.  The rest belongs to New York (because the island lies west of the center line).

Comment: @phoog Fair enough - I conflated the two islands.  Point still stands though about NY and NJ both having had claims on the island.  It seems to be officially resolved for now (as of 1998), but was definitely the source of border disputes for some time.  Given that it's uninhabited, it's kind of an academic point, though I suppose there's still dispute over which state gets the tourism money and that sort of thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How could Philadelphia join New Jersey?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/how-could-philadelphia-join-new-jersey) - It's about a specific city and state instead of a county and more general, but it's the same concept, with the same answers.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I think I have heard of other border disputes between states based on rivers and such, but none of those are about an inhabited area _voluntarily_ choosing to change.

Comment: @Rain Willow: Yes, the counties that left the state of Virginia joined another state.  It just happened to be a newly-created one.

Answer (score 14):

As [said](https://www.annenbergclassroom.org/article-iv-section-3/) in the US constitution:

> Article IV, Section 3, Clause 1 of the US Constitution states: New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new States shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States, or parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the States concerned as well as of the Congress.

States border changes between two are related to "parts of States", I think. And it is logical - that it should be admitted by both states Legislatures + Congress.

So, seems, that it is possible, but hard to achieve.

Also, there is some fresh [example](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2020/02/17/oregon-idaho-border-petition-secede/4789936002/) of an attempt.

Comment: The passage you quoted is not as straightforward as you might think interpretation-wise; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_v._West_Virginia#Assessment "Should the phrase between the first and second semicolons be read as absolutely barring the creation of a state within the jurisdiction of an existing state, or should it be read in conjunction with the following clause (which permits such creation with the consent of the existing state)?"

Comment: @Fizz, I'm also not very sure about it - so I've added ", I think". But it seems logical enough, to treat it so. So, I've posted that answer.

Comment: From the same wiki article, the US Supreme Court seems to have developed a tacit approval ("implied consent") doctrine regarding Congress actions on such matters, so your first para under the quote is also a bit misleading.

Comment: While that quote prohibits the *creation* of **new** States from parts of existing States, it doesn't answer whether or not moving a geographical boundary to make State A smaller and existing State B larger by the same amount falls under that restriction.  (And, if permitted, does the County have to be adjacent to the State it wants to join, or is it able to become an [exclave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclave_and_exclave), such as if [Cheyenne County, CO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne_County,_Colorado) wanted to join Texas)

Comment: @Chronocidal: The quote does address that. After such an event, State B would be formed by the junction of two or more states or parts of states. So, the Constitution says this can be allowed only with the consent of both states concerned as well as of the Congress.

Comment: @NickMatteo But it's not a *new* State.  There's a difference between "forming a State" and "expanding a State".  If making a State larger required approval by Congress, then Hawaii would be in there almost every month!  (it's grown by more than 500 acres - or about 380 football pitches - over the past 30 years)  Per [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/how-could-philadelphia-join-new-jersey), the actual issue would be that moving the border is an interstate compact - Article IV of the Constitution doesn't apply, but Article I, Section 10, Clause 3 *does*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's been done before.

Jones County in Mississippi along with a couple neighboring counties succeeded from both the Union and the Confederacy during the US Civil War.

There is a 2016 movie Called Free State of Jones about this.

Comment: It's a little hard to say that they succesfully seceded, given their independence didn't last beyond the civil war. And the civil war established that backing out of the union isn't possible.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum: No, it didn't establish that backing out of the union isn't possible, it just established that you need either a bigger army (and supporting industrial base) or a Federal leadership that isn't willing to slaughter more than half a million people in order to keep you in their control.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, but not because of the Statehood Clause.  That clause is about adding *new* states, and is silent about changes to an *existing* state.

However, if all four of the following groups voted in favor of the change

1. The population of the county
2. The old state
3. The new state
4. Congress

then there is no party left *with legal standing* in court to sue to stop the change.  Any attempt to stop the change in the courts would be thrown out, and the change would be accepted *de facto*.

Comment: Even if "the population of the county" votes in favor of the change, couldn't there be some folks in the minority who would still have standing to sue?  Maybe, for example, the old state has no income tax and the new state does.  Even if 99% of the county residents vote to change to the new state, someone whose tax bill goes up might contend that they were financially damaged by the change and therefore that they have standing to sue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few cases where things like this have happened(or come close to happening). You don't hear about the most popular time when it did because is immediately preceded WW2.

> Since the mid-19th century, the mountainous region of northern California and parts of southwestern Oregon have been proposed as a separate state. In 1941, some counties in the area ceremonially seceded, one day a week, from their respective states as the State of Jefferson. This movement disappeared after America's entry into World War II, but the notion has been rekindled in recent years.

[Partition and secession in California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_and_secession_in_California)

[Jefferson (proposed Pacific state)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_(proposed_Pacific_state))

It doesn't appear that any of these officially seceded, but they came very close. In the articles they talk a little bit about the procedure of how they planned on creating a new state, Worth a look if you were not aware that this had happened. This is a case of counties in states A and B coming together to form a state and not counties moving to a separate state.